# Is it possible to adjust the timeout for ffmpeg on SDP?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have `rtpdump` files that I would like to be able to convert to `webm` or `mp4` on demand and on the fly. To do this, I'm streaming their packets out extremely rapidly and having `ffmpeg` read them in using an SDP file. The packets come through and are transcoded in a second or two, since the videos are fairly short. But then there is an additional 10-second wait afterward because the `ffmpeg` network timeout for SDP defaults to 10 seconds; I'd like to reduce it. Unfortunately, the `-timeout` and `-stimeout` options don't seem to be available when I'm using `-i` with an SDP file (I get `-timeout option not found`).

I looked around online, and it seems that 6 or 7 years ago people were having similar issues and some people made pull requests into FFmpeg to add this as an option for RSTP and SDP. I know this went through for RSTP because it's in the documentation know; did anything ever happen with SDP? Is it possible for me to set this option, or maybe to terminate ffmpeg manually when I know the stream is done?